# iptables routing of wlan0 to usb0 and usb1

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

Server:

- wlan0 (WAN) - 192.168.0.17
- usb0 (LAN) - 192.168.2.15

Client:

- usb1 (LAN) - 192.168.2.2

wlan0 <-> usb0 <-> usb1

How do I configure a NAT to share my wlan0 internet access to my client usb1, through the servers usb0 using iptables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. Allow IPv4 forwarding

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
2. Make sure that your routing able (`ip route show`) has a default on `wlan0`.
3. Enable NAT:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
4. make sure that the client has the server as gateway: on the client, **if** it is a Linux machine,

   ```
   ip route del default
   ip route add default via 192.168.2.15
   ```

Comment: On the client machine I had to use:
route add default gw 192.168.2.15

Other than that it worked perfectly! thank you!

Comment: @MatBee That's the old-style command, which is now obsolete. Don't you have the **iproute2** package on the client?

Comment: Nope, I guess not. I'm using an Intel Edison using Yocto Linux. I'll see if I can get that package though.